# How to configure the bridge over bonding in RHEL 6.4 Server?

Tags: linux, networking, bridge, rhel6, bonding

Has installed a system (rhel-server-6.4-x86_64-dvd.iso). KVM over which set. The host machine and the guest-machine assigned its own IP-address, configured for this bridge **br0**. Everything works. Now we must make a bridge over bonding.

Put on the host the following settings:

```
[root@server ~]# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 
DEVICE=eth0
HWADDR=f0:92:1c:0f:76:f8
MASTER=bond0
SLAVE=yes
ONBOOT=yes

[root@server ~]# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1
DEVICE=eth1
HWADDR=F0:92:1C:0F:76:FC
MASTER=bond0
SLAVE=yes
ONBOOT=yes

[root@server ~]# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-bond0 
DEVICE=bond0
ONBOOT=yes
BRIDGE="br0"

[root@server ~]# cat /etc/modprobe.conf 
alias bond0 bonding
options bond0 mode=1 miimon=100

[root@server ~]# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-br0 
DEVICE="br0"
NM_CONTROLLED="no"
ONBOOT="yes"
TYPE="Bridge"
BOOTPROTO="static"
IPADDR="10.2.26.39"
GATEWAY="10.2.26.1"
MTU="1500"
NETMASK="255.255.255.0"
DEFROUTE="yes"
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL="yes"
IPV6INIT="no"
NAME="System br0"
```

Check out:

```
[root@server ~]# cat /proc/net/bonding/bond0
Ethernet Channel Bonding Driver: v3.6.0 (September 26, 2009)

Bonding Mode: fault-tolerance (active-backup)
Primary Slave: None
Currently Active Slave: eth1
MII Status: up
MII Polling Interval (ms): 100
Up Delay (ms): 0
Down Delay (ms): 0

Slave Interface: eth0
MII Status: down
Speed: Unknown
Duplex: Unknown
Link Failure Count: 0
Permanent HW addr: f0:92:1c:0f:76:f8
Slave queue ID: 0

Slave Interface: eth1
MII Status: up
Speed: 10000 Mbps
Duplex: full
Link Failure Count: 0
Permanent HW addr: f0:92:1c:0f:76:fc
Slave queue ID: 0
```

**eth0** was down for. Although I was expecting to see something like the following:

```
[root@server ~]# cat /proc/net/bonding/bond0
Ethernet Channel Bonding Driver: v3.6.0 (September 26, 2009)

Bonding Mode: fault-tolerance (active-backup)
Primary Slave: None
Currently Active Slave: eth0
MII Status: up
MII Polling Interval (ms): 100
Up Delay (ms): 0
Down Delay (ms): 0

Slave Interface: eth0
MII Status: up
Speed: 10000 Mbps
Duplex: full
Link Failure Count: 0
Permanent HW addr: f0:92:1c:0f:d5:e8
Slave queue ID: 0

Slave Interface: eth1
MII Status: up
Speed: 10000 Mbps
Duplex: full
Link Failure Count: 0
Permanent HW addr: f0:92:1c:0f:d5:ec
Slave queue ID: 0
```

The question itself in a subject, how to configure bridge over bonding in RHEL 6.4 Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct configuration, though a couple of points:

- You don't need to `alias bond0 bonding` at all
- Bonding configuration should be as `BONDING_OPTS` in the ifcfg-bondX, not in modprobe
- Add a `DELAY=0` to your bridge, to prevent it waiting on interface start

The fact that eth0 is down has nothing to do with bridging or bonding, troubleshoot the physical interface. `ethtool eth0` will show you it has no link detected.

Reseat the cable, replace the cable, try a different switchport, try a different NIC.